# SAP:PARSING error while calling SAP sRFC FM

Tags: mule, mule4, saprfc

SAP Flow:

```
<sap:sap-config name="SAP_Config" doc:name="SAP Config" doc:id="03c25b56-7372-4722-92d0-ce2ef568184c" >
    <sap:simple-connection-provider-connection username="${sap.username}" password="${sap.password}" systemNumber="${sap.systemNumber}" client="${sap.client}" applicationServerHost="${sap.host}" />
</sap:sap-config>
```

```
<flow name="mule-sap-demoFlow2" doc:id="9291c5c3-319d-4a4e-a5f8-ed0de66b63d5" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="7068cc2f-2147-4334-a6e7-189352d9ef54" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/sap"/>
        <sap:sync-rfc key="${function.key}" doc:name="Synchronous Remote Function Call" doc:id="5bca83af-159b-4fa2-8872-76fefd79be92" config-ref="SAP_Config"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="bd0b00f4-8acb-4823-a99e-9e39c1c4fe18" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
```

Error:

```
INFO  2020-08-06 16:02:51,335 [[MuleRuntime].uber.02: [mule-mongo-demo].mule-mongo-demoFlow2.BLOCKING @301a4df3] [processor: ; event: 2df0b2e0-d7d0-11ea-93c5-506b8d070e10] com.mulesoft.connector.sap.internal.service.impl.BAPIFunctionJCoService: Use SAP default format 'false'.
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.
ERROR 2020-08-06 16:02:51,366 [[MuleRuntime].uber.02: [mule-mongo-demo].mule-mongo-demoFlow2.BLOCKING @301a4df3] [processor: ; event: 2df0b2e0-d7d0-11ea-93c5-506b8d070e10] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: 

Message               : An exception occurred while parsing XML.
Element               : mule-sap-demoFlow2/processors/0 @ mule-sap-demo:mule-mongo-demo.xml:161 (Synchronous Remote Function Call)
Element DSL           : <sap:sync-rfc key="" doc:name="Synchronous Remote Function Call" doc:id="5bca83af-159b-4fa2-8872-76fefd79be92" config-ref="SAP_Config"></sap:sync-rfc>
Error type            : SAP:PARSING
FlowStack             : at mule-sap-demoFlow2(mule-mongo-demoFlow2/processors/0 @ mule-mongo-demo:mule-mongo-demo.xml:161 (Synchronous Remote Function Call))

  (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the connector is failing to parse some XML data. It is difficult to say exactly without more details but it looks like the connector is expecting some XML and it is not receiving it from the HTTP Listener, or it is not receiving a valid XML response back from SAP. Be sure to use the [latest version of the SAP connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/connector/sap-connector-release-notes-mule-4). Previous versions had a bug parsing XML with the character 0x0.

Comment: I am using the latest version 5.1.7

Comment: Are you sure the response is non empty?

Comment: Yes, It was issue from SAP side. the user didn't have required permissions after getting permission it is able to return data

Comment: Ok that seems to match with `not receiving a valid XML response back from SAP`.